# find cosine similarity between words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, sklearn-pandas, cosine-similarity

Is it possible to find similarity between two words? For example:

```
cos_lib = cosine_similarity('kamra', 'cameras')
```

This gives me an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'kamra'
```

because I haven't converted the words into numerical vectors. How can I do so? I tried this but it wouldn't work either:

```
('kamra').toarray()
```

My aim is to check the similarity with both value(lists) of my dictionary and return the key with the highest similarity. Is that possible?

```
features = {"CAMERA": ['camera', 'kamras'], "BATTERY": ['batterie', 'battery']}
```

I also tried this but I am not satisfied with the results:

```
print(damerau.distance('dual camera', 'cameras'))
print(damerau.distance('kamra', 'battery'))
```

since the results are 6 and 5. But the similar between the first two strings is more so the distance should be less. That's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What kind of similarity are you after? Would Levenshtein/edit distance be sufficient?

Comment: Cosine distance is always defined between two real vectors of same length. For words, check out `minimum edit distance`.

Comment: Your have still not defined what *exactly* does similarity mean to you. But perhaps you can normalize the edit distance by the combined length of the items?

Comment: which library are you using? were does the function "cosine_similarity()" come from?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a pre-trained model from [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html). You can can download a pre-trained model and then get the cosine similarity between their two vectors.

```
import gensim.downloader as api
# overview of all models in gensim: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data
model_glove = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")

model_glove.relative_cosine_similarity("politics", "vote")
# output: 0.07345439049627836
model_glove.relative_cosine_similarity("film", "camera")
# output: 0.06281138757741007
model_glove.relative_cosine_similarity("economy", "fart")
# output: -0.01170896437873441
```

Pretrained models will have a hard time recognising typos though, because they were probably not in the training data. Figuring these out is a separate task from cosine similarity.

```
model_glove.relative_cosine_similarity("kamra", "cameras")
# output: -0.040658474068872255
```

The following function might be useful though, if you have several words and you want to have the most similar one from the list:

```
model_glove.most_similar_to_given("camera", ["kamra", "movie", "politics", "umbrella", "beach"])
# output: 'movie'
```

Answer (score 1):

Cosine distance is always defined between two real vectors of same length.

As for words/sentences/strings, there are two kinds of distances:

**Minimum Edit Distance:** This is the number of changes required to make two words have the same characters. The words need not have any meaning for MED to be defined. For example, the strings `abcd` and `abed` have `MED = 1`. But they have no real meaning in language.

**Semantic distance:** This is a measure of how far apart words are in terms of meaning. As such, you need a *vocabulary* here, on top of which a model is built. Here, words are converted into numerical vectors representing their relative meaning. For example, vectors representing `tree` and `wood` would be closer than vectors for `king` and `queen`. Vector representations of words can be obtained using common models like `Word2Vec` or high-end Neural Networks like `BERT` or `GPT-2`. Cosine distance between vector representations is a type of semantic distance. Another type of semantic distance is Euclidean Distance.

**Note:** In case of semantic representations, all words that do not match any word in the vocabulary (eg `kamra`, `abcxyz`) would all be grouped under one meaning, represening {unknown word}.

For your particular use case, I would suggest running MED to get the most probable word from the vocabulary, followed by some form of semantic distance. You can try some autocorrection APIs for the former.

Answer (score -1):

Luckily, there are libraries that do exactly that, such as [word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). You would need to train it on some corpus of data or download a pre-trained model (for your specific language or set of languages).